# How To Paste Variables into Formula

Tags: r, error-handling, formula, paste

I'm getting a peculiar error when I try to paste variables into my formula. I have the following variables:

```
# Choose explanatory variables 
vars_int <- c("age", 
              "male", 
              "race_ethnicity", 
              "patient_regional_location", 
              "marital_status", 
              "total_admits", 
              "chf", 
              "copd", 
              "diabwc", 
              "mld", 
              "cevd",
              "Obesity", 
              "Smoking")
```

When I copy them directly into a formula, everything works fine:

```
# Generate inverse probability weights 
wts_17 <-  ipwpoint(
  exposure = exposure,
  family = "binomial",  
  link = "logit",
  denominator = ~ 
    age + 
    male + 
    race_ethnicity + 
    patient_regional_location + 
    marital_status + 
    total_admits + 
    chf + 
    copd + 
    diabwc + 
    mld + 
    cevd + 
    Obesity +
    Smoking,   
  data = df_17)
```

But then when I try to do it using a past function, everything falls apart:

```
paste("~", paste(vars_int, collapse = " + "))
[1] "~ age + male + race_ethnicity + patient_regional_location + marital_status + total_admits + chf + copd + diabwc + mld + cevd + Obesity + Smoking"

> wts_17 <-  ipwpoint(
+   exposure = exposure,
+   family = "binomial",  
+   link = "logit",
+   denominator = paste("~", paste(vars_int, collapse = " + ")),  
+   data = df_17)
Error in ipwpoint(exposure = exposure, family = "binomial", link = "logit",  : 
  Invalid denominator formula specified
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: I think it's because the formula is a string and not a formula.  What if you wrap `as.formula()` around your paste statement, or use `reformulate(vars_int)` instead of the paste function to make the formula?

Comment: Great idea! I tried that but got a new error message, working on it now:

Comment: > wts_17 <-  ipwpoint(
+   exposure = exposure,
+   family = "binomial",  
+   link = "logit",
+   denominator = reformulate(vars_int), 
+   data = df_17)
Error in exposurereformulate(vars_int) : 
  could not find function "exposurereformulate"